# Javascript create iFrame dom innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

gives Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

```
var f = document.createElement("iframe");
f.id = "s";
f.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "body";
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: f is not an iframe

Comment: what do you mean
of course. Yes but this problem i again see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add content to iframe, you should pass by **src** attribute,
here is an example.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); 
var html = '<body>Foo</body>'; 
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html); document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

if your content is url, you put it directly into src,like this

```
iframe.src="https://www.w3schools.com"
```

Comment: i dont want use src because i will use many many iframe.
and i can not read they.

Comment: for each iframe you mention its src